# Last loaded URL of CURL resource

Tags: php, curl

I'm writing something a little complex with CURL. I happened to have a situation where I need to know the last URL CURL has loaded (if it was redirected) or just the original URL from `curl_init($url)`.

I guess that if it was redirected, I can parse the `Location` header:

```
if(preg_match('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $headers, $matches)>0) {
   echo "Final location is: {$matches[1]}\n";  //We know location thanks to follow location
}
else {
   echo "Well, I'm doomed...\n";  //We don't know anything
}
```

This is, by the way, the reason I don't like resources in PHP so hard.

**On a second thought** I realised that the script above will not work - the last page you load upon redirection does not send any `Location` header. Otherwise you'd be redirected again!

Comment: On a second thought: The **last page** does not send location - unless the [redirection limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS) is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$last_URL = curl_getinfo ( $ch ,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL   );
```

P.S: If the CURL  reaches  redirection limit or `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is set to false (e.g in safe mode) , then you should check for Location header.